# Comments with `code ticked` text with large spaces seems to leak onto other parts of the page

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

I posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646757/how-to-fix-nuget-provider-find-module-installation-error-with-powershell-7-3?noredirect=1#comment131764240_74646757) on Stack Overflow with the following text:

```
@DougMaurer that command returns `Cmdlet          Get-PackageProvider                                1.4.8.1    PackageManagement`
```

It looked like this after posting:

[image: comment with code formatting leaking into other parts of page]

I am assuming the weird spacing of the comment caused it to leak into the other parts of the page?  The reason the spacing was there was because I simply copy and pasted the text I got back in PowerShell when I ran the command asked by Doug Maurer.